# Swift performance on pixel processing

Tags: objective-c, swift, image-processing

I have to do a swift function for detecting the size of the areas of a certain color. The function I wrote but can not get the processing speed I have for the same function in Objective C.

After a few days of optimization, on the iPhone 7Plus and a 2048x2048 image, the search for 256 zones occupies 1.04s on ObjectiveC and 2.5s on Swift.

What have I missed and where can Swift code be optimized?

```
@IBAction func allZonesOpt(_ sender: Any) {
        let startDate = Date()

        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"idx.png")!

        let cgImage : CGImage = image.cgImage!
        guard let pixelData = CGDataProvider(data: (cgImage.dataProvider?.data)!)?.data else {
            return
        }
        let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)!
        let numberOfComponents:Int = 4

        let imageWidth = Int(image.size.width)
        let imageHeight = Int(image.size.height)
        let bytesPerRow = imageWidth * numberOfComponents


        let rangeOne = 0..<Int(image.size.height)
        let rangeTwo = 0..<Int(image.size.width)
        var arrayWithZones = [(Int, Int)]()

        for colorRed:UInt8 in 0...255 {
          //  autoreleasepool {
                let colorR = colorRed
                let colorG = 0
                let colorB = 0


                var minx:Int = imageWidth
                var miny:Int = imageHeight
                var maxx:Int = 0
                var maxy:Int = 0
                let startDateFor = Date()
            for y in rangeOne {
                for x in rangeTwo {
                        let pixelData = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * numberOfComponents

                        if data[pixelData] == colorR && data[pixelData + 1] == colorG && data[pixelData+2] == colorB{
                            if minx > x{
                                minx = x
                            }
                            if miny > y{
                                miny = y
                            }
                            if maxx < x{
                                maxx = x
                            }
                            if maxy < y{
                                maxy = y
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                let methodFinishFor = Date()
                let timeIntervalFor = methodFinishFor.timeIntervalSince(startDateFor)
                print(" time execution = \(timeIntervalFor)")
                arrayWithZones.append((maxx - minx, maxy - miny))
               // let finalSize = CGSize(width: maxx - minx, height: maxy - miny)
               // print("final = \(finalSize)")
           // }
        }


        let methodFinish = Date()
        let timeInterval = methodFinish.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
        resultLabel.text = " time execution = \(timeInterval)"
        print(" time execution = \(timeInterval)")
        print("atFinal = \(arrayWithZones)");
    }
```

Objective-C:

```
- (IBAction)allZonesAsSwift:(id)sender {
    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"idx.png"];

    //static rawData
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    unsigned int width = (unsigned int)CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    unsigned int height = (unsigned int)CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;

    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
    const unsigned char * rawData =  CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

    unsigned int minx = image.size.width;
    unsigned int miny = image.size.height;
    unsigned int maxx = 0;
    unsigned int maxy = 0;

    unsigned char colorR = 0;
    unsigned char colorG = 0;
    unsigned char colorB = 0;

    NSMutableArray *arrayWithZones = [NSMutableArray<NSValue*> new];

    for (int colorRed = 0; colorRed < 256; colorRed ++) {
        colorR = (unsigned char)colorRed;

        minx = (unsigned  int)image.size.width;
        miny = (unsigned int)image.size.height;
        maxx = 0;
        maxy = 0;
        NSDate *methodStartFor = [NSDate date];
        for (unsigned int y = height - 1; y; y--) {
            for (unsigned int x = width - 1; x; x--) {
                unsigned int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;

                if (rawData[byteIndex] == colorR && rawData[byteIndex + 1] == colorG && rawData[byteIndex + 2] == colorB) {
                    minx = x < minx ? x : minx;
                    maxx = x > maxx ? x : maxx;
                    miny = y < miny ? y : miny;
                    maxy = y > maxy ? y : maxy;
                }
            }
        }

        NSDate *methodFinishFor = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval executionTimeFor = [methodFinishFor timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStartFor];
        NSLog(@"executionTime Zone = %f", executionTimeFor);

        CGSize final = CGSizeMake(maxx - minx, maxy - miny);
        [arrayWithZones addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:final]];
    }

    free(rawData);

    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
    NSLog(@"color picker = %f", executionTime);
    _resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"color picker = %f", executionTime];
    NSLog(@"final = %@", arrayWithZones);
}
```

Comment: Did you turn on compiler optimizations? That is important to do before timing Swift code (as with C and C++, but not Objective-C). https://yalantis.com/blog/is-swift-faster-than-objective-c/

Comment: @CrisLuengo  It is just as important in Objective-C.   While method call sites cannot be optimized away, alll the rest of the surrounding code can.   Like, for example, those nested for() loops;   those are ripe for optimization.

Comment: Have you profiled the code?   There are some excellent tools included with the Xcode suite for profiling this sort of thing.   I'd start there.  One hint;  modify your code to do the operation 10 times in a row.   That kind repetition makes tracking performance issues easier.   Also, it is likely that the GPU can be leveraged to do this sort of thing much much faster than the CPU (using Metal 2).

Comment: In all cases code is runned in release mode with all optimisations, speed problem is in for loop, for swift i test with while loop but speed decreased to 3.8s. GPU processing can help, i write all other steps on the GPU, but the main question is :"Why swift is so slow wit agressive optimization?"